# Palinderome in single tape TM in O(n^2)

Tags: computational-complexity

It is known that:

(1) Palindrome can be recognized by two-tape TM in O(N)
(2) Palindrome can be recognized by one-tape TM in O(N^2)

Question: do we actually have proof that a one-tape TM can't recognize Palindrome faster than O(N^2)?

[I have some handwavy intuition on why it "must" run back & forth over the tape; but nothing that I can formalize into a proof.]

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is known.  I believe the result is due to Cobham.

Comment: Please correct the misspelling in the title.

Answer (score 3):

The (IMO) easiest way to formalize your intuition is using the language of communication complexity.  For example, a proof that palindromes require $\Omega(n^2)$ time on a one-tape, one-head machine is given in "Communication Complexity" by Kushilevitz and Nisan.  If all you want is the palindrome proof, you could read chapters 1 and 2 and then jump to chapter 12.

Another popular proof uses the notion of a "crossing sequence".  A good reference for that proof is in Lecture 1 of Kozen's "Theory of Computation".  Essentially, this is the same as the communication proof, but in different words.